# How to track where people come from to my google play market game page

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to track where people come to my game page on google market ?

For example, I want to find all web pages that link to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=MYGAME_ID - how can you do that?

I had some big spike in app downloads a few days ago and I'm trying to figure out what was the  cause. I assume that maybe one of the review websites published a review for my app, but I cannot figure out which one.

Google Analitics overview mentions that it makes it possible to track how user find the app, but I failed to understand how installation of their SDK in the app could help. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried doing a search on your app name?

Comment: i think you should implement google analytics in your app.that might do your job..Check this link https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate Google Analytics for your App to get proper tracking:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns